# Deadspace at side of screen on mobile with Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm building a frontend with Next.js and Tailwind. There is a problem whereby deadspace exist on screens of width < 500px.

For example, if the screen is 400px wide, the deadspace will be 100px wide. Or if the screen is 350px wide the deadspace will be 150px.

When the page is loaded on a smaller screen (< 500px), the full width will be displayed (rendered area + deadspace).

As can be seen in the screenshot below, it doesn't appear to be a layout / nesting issue as even the root `<html>` element is 400px wide.

[image]

See live site [here](https://eminence-website.vercel.app) where the code can be inspected via devtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this banner which is overflowing the viewport:

[image: Overflowing banner]

Which is mainly due to this inner element which has a static width:

[image: Inner static width element]

Since you have all the child elements hidden until the `md` breakpoint anyway, you could consider hiding this parent element instead:

```html
<div class="hidden md:flex w-80 flex-row justify-between lg:ml-20">
  <h6 class="flex"><a href="/projects">Projects</a></h6>
  <h6 class="flex"><a href="/about">About us</a></h6>
  <h6 class="flex">Contact</h6>
</div>
```

After this is changed, you will still get some overflow and it is due to this element:

[image: Overflow hero caption]

This is due to its static width from the `w-96` class. You could consider using  `max-width` instead so that it can shrink:

```html
<h1 class="mt-36 max-w-sm text-center text-5xl/tight font-normal md:mt-48 md:w-[46rem] md:text-8xl/tight">The Builder Of Opportunities</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Don't know how I missed that!